# Lombok getters and setters not recognized by compiler

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I use Lombok on a maven project. The plugin is installed and seems to be working just fine. That is, until I hit the build button. Then the compiler says:

> java: cannot find symbol
> symbol:   method getName()
> location: variable resourceDAO of type mydirectory.rest.dao.ResourceDAO

referencing a class

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ResourceDAO extends EntityDAO {

    private String name;
    // ...

}
```

the maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.24</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The IDE doesn't complain about it. Why does the compiler?

Comment: I'm not sure tbh - In the meantime I used IntelliJ's code generation shortcut to semi-automatically get rid of Lombok. Now the code looks ugly but at least it works.

Comment: Which build button, from your IDE or a maven goal?